# GitHub Actions edit comment

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to edit a comment using GitHub Actions?

I would like to make sure that, every time a comment is made, the possibility of being able to analyze the text (comment) to do certain editing operations in the event.

Answer (score 0):

Is it like creating/editing a Comment for a pull request?

If so you can find it on Github Marketplace
https://github.com/marketplace

And make the changes based on event no.

```
${{ github.event.number }}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32239472)